# APACHE AND PHP PERMISSIONS

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost, vps

So for a project i Made i setup multiple subdomains,

I Have: website.me
And i Have: play.website.me

My php code in the subdomain (htdocs/client/index.php) =

recuire_once '../Global.php';

But it says that i DONT Have PERMISSIONS to access the php code. (Photo 1)

How do i fix this (photo 2 is my vhost configuration)

Comment: Oops, couldnt add photos in my First question, ill add link to photos if you ask for them.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bu1Q1R (1) | https://ibb.co/cjt51R (2)